# presto hive: Query failed: Partition location does not exist:

Tags: linux, hadoop, hive, presto

I have presto server(linux) with config.properties:

```
coordinator=false
datasources=hive
node-scheduler.include-coordinator=false
http-server.http.port=8080
query.max-memory=5GB
query.max-memory-per-node=1GB
discovery-server.enabled=true
discovery.uri=http://localhost:8080
```

And catalog/hive.properties:

```
connector.name=hive-cdh4
hive.metastore.uri=thrift://another-machine:port
```

Hive are working on another mashine (windows(!)).
Db client works correct with hive. Tables can be created, updated etc.

But if I use presto client (presto.jar from linux) 
ERROR:

```
Query 20160426_133746_00003_8iq7y failed: Partition location does not exist: file:/C:/tmp/user/hive/warehouse/test
```

Path is correct. Exist.

hive-site.xml config contains:

```
<property>
   <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
   <value>file:///C:/tmp/user/hive/warehouse</value>
   <description>location of the warehouse directory</description>
 </property>
```

Need help to resolve this problem. Thanks.